# Are there any museums or sites in England or Scotland honouring James Watt?

Tags: museums, england, scotland, geek-travel, science

I'm travelling to the UK from Australia and wanted to visit a number of sites of scientific history.

One at the top of my list is [James Watt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Watt). (inventor/perfector of Steam Engine - a fundamental part of the Industrial Revolution).

I understand there is a working Boulton and Watt engine [at the museum](http://www.nms.ac.uk/explore/stories/science-and-technology/boulton-and-watt-engine/) of Scotland.

There appears to be a [display of his life](http://www.sciencemuseum.org.uk/visitmuseum/plan_your_visit/exhibitions/james_watt_and_our_world) at museum in London.

There appears to be a [steam engine in a restored mill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Lanark) in New Lanark.

The closest seems to be [a display](http://www.waterandsteam.org.uk/learning/jameswatt) the London Museum of Water and steam.

But can you visit a museum with a display about his life and works?

My question is: **Are there any museums or sites in England or Scotland honouring James Watt?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to your research, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Watt) suggests a few more options:

> Watt was buried in the grounds of **St. Mary's Church, Handsworth**, in Birmingham. Later expansion of the church, over his grave, means that his tomb is now buried inside the church.
>
> The approximate location of James Watt's birth in **Greenock** is commemorated by a statue. Several locations and street names in Greenock recall him, most notably the **Watt Memorial Library**, which was begun in 1816 with Watt's donation of scientific books, and developed as part of the Watt Institution by his son (which ultimately became the **James Watt College**). Taken over by the local authority in 1974, the library now also houses the local history collection and archives of Inverclyde, and is dominated by a **large seated statue in the vestibule**. Watt is additionally commemorated by **statuary** in George Square, Glasgow and Princes Street, Edinburgh, as well as several others in Birmingham, where he is also remembered by the Moonstones and a school is named in his honour.
>
> The James Watt College has expanded from its original location to include campuses in Kilwinning (North Ayrshire), Finnart Street and The Waterfront in Greenock, and the Sports campus in Largs. Heriot-Watt University near Edinburgh was at one time the School of Arts of Edinburgh, founded in 1821 as the world's first Mechanics Institute, but to commemorate George Heriot, the 16th-century financier to King James, and James Watt, after Royal Charter the name was changed to **Heriot-Watt University**. Dozens of university and college buildings (chiefly of science and technology) are named after him. Matthew Boulton's home, **Soho House**, is now a museum, commemorating the work of both men. The University of Glasgow's Faculty of Engineering has its headquarters in the James Watt Building, which also houses the department of Mechanical Engineering and the department of Aerospace Engineering. The huge **painting** James Watt contemplating the steam engine by James Eckford Lauder is now owned by the National Gallery of Scotland.
>
> **Chantrey's statue of James Watt**
>   There is a statue of James Watt in Piccadilly Gardens, Manchester and City Square, Leeds.
>
> A colossal statue of Watt by Chantrey was placed in **Westminster Abbey**, and later was moved to St. Paul's Cathedral. On the cenotaph the inscription reads, in part, "JAMES WATT ... ENLARGED THE RESOURCES OF HIS COUNTRY, INCREASED THE POWER OF MAN, AND ROSE TO AN EMINENT PLACE AMONG THE MOST ILLUSTRIOUS FOLLOWERS OF SCIENCE AND THE REAL BENEFACTORS OF THE WORLD."